# Clearing the search history in the official Twitter app?

Tags: twitter, search-history

Is there an easier way to clear your Twitter app's search history aside from removing your Twitter account and re-adding it or deleting the application's data under **Settings > Applications > Manage Applications > Twitter**?

This functionality does not appear to exist in the official Twitter for Android app.